# How to run certain launch files within nodes?

Tags: slam, python, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on an autonomous which requires different modes in which the robot will be running at. One such mode is a SLAM mode, but I feel that running SLAM for the whole time that the robot is running would be extremely inefficient. Is it possible to run SLAM only when a certain condition is met? Would this condition go in the .launch file or in some node? (for example, when a certain distance is travelled by the robot).

I am writing in python.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265990/how-to-run-certain-launch-files-within-nodes?/) by [snuzero](https://answers.ros.org/users/31106/snuzero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi snuzero,

I hope you have found a solution by now but I thought I would post an answer if case anyone else comes looking.

Adding the following to your launch file should do the trick.

```
<launch>
    <group if="$(arg foo)">
        <include file="$(find pkg)/launch/launch_name.launch"/>
    </group>

    <!-- The stuff you want to run in all cases -->
</launch>
```

In the included launch file, add your SLAM nodes.

Wiki on the include tag: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/include

If you want to start nodes dynamically, I would recommend launching them anyway but add a dynamic parameter to them which will only activate them when set. I.e. set up the node to periodically check for the given parameter, when set, do something but keep checking. This should allow you, or another node, to activate it using the rosparam server.

---

Originally posted by [Tyrone Nowell](https://answers.ros.org/users/28295/tyrone-nowell/) with karma: 48 on 2018-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0